# why can't run cell "tweet_df = load_data()"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk
import string
import re

def load_data():
    data = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')
    return data

tweet_df = load_data()
```

I want to load "twitter.csv" data, which contains the crawled results of 1000 tweet data.
but error and generate code like the following

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <module>
----> 1 tweet_df = load_data()

Input In [2], in load_data()
      1 def load_data():
----> 2     data = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')
      3     return data

File c:\users\asus\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py:311, in deprecate_nonkeyword_arguments.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    305 if len(args) > num_allow_args:
    306     warnings.warn(
    307         msg.format(arguments=arguments),
    308         FutureWarning,
    309         stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310     )
--> 311 return func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you add sample `twitter.csv` here

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lk2-ejYWbCmMJQaE94pnkh1dAfW-4N0P/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The twitter data is semi-colon separated so you need to provide `delimiter` or `sep` argument

```
def load_data(file_name, delim):
    data = pd.read_csv(file_name,delimiter=delim)
    return data

tweet_df = load_data('twitter.csv',delim=';')
```

the pandas can infer delimiter if you use `engine='python'` argument in the read_csv refer documentation the argument `sep` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using up to date pandas package?

Try `pip3 install --upgrade pandas`

Assuming you use pip to manage packages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).